# Toggle mc play/pause button for music doesn't work. Music linked for export (AS) in library

Tags: android, actionscript-3, button, mp3

I'm new to Actionscript 3 and using Flash CS6.

-I'm trying to play/pause a 20 minute mp3 named countrymeadow

-countrymeadow.mp3 is linked for Export for actionscript (countrymeadow) in the Library.

- playpause mc button is stopped in the 1st frame(play) and 10th frame(pause) inside the button.
- AS3 is below for it but it is not working as the mc playpause button constantly toggles between 'play' and 'pause' when tested plus no sound is played.

Any help is appreciated, and many thanks in advance.

```
//set appearance of button, mode to true
playpause_mc.gotoAndStop("play");
playpause_mc.buttonMode = true;

//sound is stopped after loaded
var isPaused:Boolean = true;

//saves current position of sound
var currPos:int = 0.00;

var theSound:countrymeadow = new countrymeadow();
snd.play(); 

var soundCnl:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

//Listener updates after sound loads, and stops           soundtheSound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);
function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
    //Stop loaded sound
    soundCnl.stop();
}


// movie clip button control
playpause_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {

    if(isPaused){
        //change state to playing, and play sound from position
        isPaused = false;
        soundCnl = theSound.play(currPos); 

        //reverse the appearance of the button
        playpause_mc.gotoAndStop("pause")

        //if sound completes while playing, run function
        soundCnl.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundCompleteHandler);

    }else{
        //it's playing, so save position and pause sound
        currPos = soundCnl.position;
        isPaused = true;
        soundCnl.stop();

        //change the appearance of the buttons
        playpause_mc.gotoAndStop("play")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SoundChannel `position` is a `Number` variable. that is range 0 to 1. but you're set `int` variable. `int` is not a floating-point type. Because you have explicitly declared as `int` type. even if when you turned into a floating point initialization, convert to `int` type.

[image]

you should following this. and your clickHandler function some corrected.

```
var currPos:Number = 0.0;

soundCnl.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundCompleteHandler);
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {

    if(isPaused){
        //change state to playing, and play sound from position
        isPaused = false;
        soundCnl.play(currPos); 

        //reverse the appearance of the button
        playpause_mc.gotoAndStop("pause")

    }else{
        //it's playing, so save position and pause sound
        currPos = soundCnl.position;
        isPaused = true;
        soundCnl.stop();

        //change the appearance of the buttons
        playpause_mc.gotoAndStop("play")
    }
}
```

---

test code:

```
var n:int = 0.0;

n = 0.5;

trace("n: " + n); //you may expected 0.5, but return 0.
```

Comment: Thanks anyway, but I don't understand what I'm supposed to replace. What shall I keep from my own code and what do I replace? Can you give a better and more detailed example instead? Re: my code with your correction included...